# M2 early patches are not available for some auth keys

Tags: magento2, patches

Magento sends an email to vendors before announcing officially about security patch to provide vendors possibility to upgrade/patch M2 beforehand.

We have two Commerce Edition projects with different credentials in `auth.json`:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "*****************",
            "password": "*****************"
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting point, that for one project, new patched M2 is available, for another - not.

The result of:

```
composer show magento/product-enterprise-edition --all
```

will provide different results. Changed to the `good` keys for testing purpose, and it works (shows all available new versions)

Have someone faced with a similar issue?

Comment: updating the `auth.json`  `composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.3 --no-update`    `composer update`  working for me

Comment: @sandip `auth.json` contains unique keys generated and provided  specifically for each project, I can not use keys from another project. so did not get your point